# Bash: execute command repeatedly and write output tab seperated to file

Tags: bash, while-loop, append, multiple-columns, do-while

I want my file to Log like that:

```
Time_Namelookup: 0,1  0,2  0,12  0,45       ...
Time_Connect: 0,34 0,23  0,23 0,11          ...
Time_Starttransfer: 0,9 0,23  0,12          ...
```

I want that Values are added to their specific line every n seconds.

I got a code like this:

```
while [ "true" ]
do 
echo "Time_Namelookup:" >> $file
curl -w "%{time_namelookup}\t" -o /dev/null -s https://website.com/
echo "Time_connect" >> $file
curl -w "%{time_connect}\t" -o /dev/null -s https://website.com/
echo "Time_Starttransfer:" >> $file
curl -w "%{time_starttransfer}\t" -o /dev/null -s https://website.com/
sleep 5
done
```

But I get something like

```
Time_Namelookup: 0,1         
Time_Connect: 0,34         
Time_Starttransfer: 0,9   

Time_Namelookup:  0,2      
Time_Connect:0,23  0,23        
Time_Starttransfer:  0,23   

Time_Namelookup:  0,45       
Time_Connect:  0,11         
Time_Starttransfer: 0,12
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You could put this inside your loop

```
if [ ! -f $file ]; then
  echo "Time_Namelookup:" > $file
  echo "Time_Connect:" >> $file
  echo "Time_Starttransfer:" >> $file
fi

name_lookup=$(curl -w "%{time_namelookup}\t" -o /dev/null -s https://website.com/)
connect=$(curl -w "%{time_connect}\t" -o /dev/null -s https://website.com/)
starttransfer=$(curl -w "%{time_starttransfer}\t" -o /dev/null -s https://website.com/)
sed -i -e "s/\(Time_Starttransfer:.*\)/\1 $starttransfer/" \
  -e "s/\(Time_Connect:.*\)/\1 $connect/" \
  -e "s/\(Time_Starttransfer:.*\)/\1 $starttransfer/" \
  $file
```

Comment: This apparently does what the OP wants, but it's absolutely hideous.  A single `sed -i -e "1s/\$/ $firstvalue/" -e "2s/\$/ $secondvalue/" -e "3s/\$/ $thirdvalue/" "$file"` would at least avoid rewriting the file multiple times per iteration.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this;

```
file=yourFile
echo "Time_Namelookup   :" >> $file
echo "Time_Connect      :" >> $file
echo "Time_Starttransfer:" >> $file
while [ "true" ]
do 
time_namelookup=$(curl -w "%{time_namelookup}\t" -o /dev/null -s https://website.com/)
time_connect=$(curl -w "%{time_connect}\t" -o /dev/null -s https://website.com/)
time_starttransfer=$(curl -w "%{time_starttransfer}\t" -o /dev/null -s https://website.com/)
sed -i "/Time_Namelookup   :/s/$/\t$time_namelookup/" $file
sed -i "/Time_Connect      :/s/$/\t$time_connect/" $file
sed -i "/Time_Starttransfer:/s/$/\t$time_starttransfer/" $file
sleep 5
done
```

`sed -i :` to be edited in-place.

The following part is to find "Time_Namelookup   :" in the file.

```
/Time_Namelookup   :/
```

/s/$/\t$time_namelookup/"

```
s         :substitute command
/../../   :delimiter
$         :end of line character.
\t$time_namelookup: to append tab and the value.
```

Comment: Great this worked. Very nice approach. could you explain me the sed part ?

Comment: @JMAD2016. I updated ans. I hope, this could help you.